# get result from connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I don't know how I get the result from connectionDidFinishLoading. I have these codes:

connect.m:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[self.dataResponse bytes] length:[self.dataResponse length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

videos.m:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Connect *connect;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.connect = [[Connect alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                       onSuccess:@selector(responseSuccess:)
                                         onError:@selector(responseError:)];
}
```

I want to know how I get, in videos.m the result from connect.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connectionDidFinishLoading` just tells your your done. You'll want to implement the protocol `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and use `connection:didReceiveData:` to gather up your data.

Be aware your data comes in in multiple chunks, so `connection:didReceiveData:` will get called multiple times and you'll have to keep appending the new chunk of data to the end until `connectionDidFinishLoading` gets called.